# Consul infrastructure footprint and performance

Tags: consul

Is there any documentation on Consul's requirements as it pertains to infrastructure footprint ? (e.g. memory / disk / cpu requirement and typical usage of Consul agents and master themselves). How does this compare with other similar service discovery solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

I know of no official documentation on this. It will depend in part on the number of total nodes you are running (i.e. server agents plus client agents on each machine running services.

[This thread](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/1723) includes comments (and a good link to a presentation by Darron at DataDog) from production users. They indicate using AWS m3.medium to m3.large instances in their production situations (you can find specs on those instance types [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)). Darron's presentation includes some information on # of nodes in their scenario as well as comments on how they scaled as the number of nodes grew.